# Assign physical camera button to another app

Tags: camera, buttons, sony-xperia-z5

Is there a way to assign the physical camera button to a camera-app other than the default camera app?

So, if the camera button is pressed, a specific app should start up.

If possible, it should also work in lock screen, and without rooting the device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way, but your device has to be rooted.

First you have to install Xposed Framework, than download and install an Xposed module called [`Xposed Additions`](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) or [`Physical Button Music Control`](http://repo.xposed.info/module/xeed.xposed.cbppmod).

After this you can able to rebind your physical buttons.